# How rotate spaceship from y-axis to left in unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, axis

I am starting a new unity3d project and i want to know how to rotate moving forward spaceship from y-axis to left and right.

```
void Update(){
   transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * 10f;
   if(input.Getkey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
   {
     //code for rotate ;
   }
}
```

I want that when I press arrow left key then spaceship rotates from y-axis to left until the arrow key released.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Transform.Rotate(Vector3).

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        transform.Rotate(transform.forward * 3);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        transform.Rotate(transform.forward * -3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont really know if i understand the question, but I think this may help you.

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)){
         transform.Rotate (new Vector3(Time.deltaTime * 0, 1, 0));
}
```

where the first 0 is for x-axis, number 1 is for y-axis and the other 0 is for z-axis

Answer (score 1):

You'll want declare the speed and rotation speed as floats so you can easily change them later, but here you go. I did both left and right.

```
float speed = 10.0f;
float rotateSpeed = 2.0f;

void Update(){
   transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed;

   if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
   {
      //code for rotate
      transform.Rotate(vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);
   }
   else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
   {
      transform.Rotate(vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);
   }
}
```

If you want to rotate the ship relative to the world then use:

```
transform.Rotate(vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed, Space.World);
```